# How to get tap position to add control?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, textbox

I have a **Windows phone 8.0** project that has an image. When the user taps on the image, I have to get the position of the tap and add a text box to this location (above image).

For now, I use the following code, but I always get a wrong position

```
        MessageBox.Show("vao day");
        var mp = GetMousePoint(e);
        MessageBox.Show("x=" + mp.X + "_" + "y=" + mp.Y);
        //x: 258; y:97
        double top= 0; double right = 0; double bottom =0; double left=0;
        top = e.GetPosition(OrginalImage).Y; //(double)mp.Y - 50;
        left = e.GetPosition(OrginalImage).X; //(double)mp.X - 50;

        MessageBox.Show("x=" + left.ToString() + "_" + "y=" + top.ToString());
        //add textbox to this position
        TextBox newtext = new TextBox();
        newtext.Text = "truongpm";
        newtext.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
        newtext.Width = 124;
        newtext.Height = 68;

        //button.VerticalAlignment = 234;
        //Add contentpanel to your page if there's not one already.
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(newtext);
        newtext.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

[image]

Can anybody help me please!
Thanks

This is my xaml code

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove" Name="OrginalImage" Stretch="Fill" Height="250" Source="/Assets/vd1.png"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="ALter" Width="100" Height="80" Click="AlterButton_Click" Foreground="#FFD66A6A" BorderBrush="#FF16C71E" Margin="10,0,360,0"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Save" Width="100" Height="80" Foreground="#FFD66A6A" BorderBrush="#FF16C71E" Margin="115,0,255,0" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Text" Width="100" Height="80" Foreground="#FFD66A6A" BorderBrush="#FF16C71E" Margin="115,0,055,0" Click="TextButton_Click"></Button>
        <Image Grid.Row="2" Name="AlterImage" />

        <!--<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Margin="110,65,0,0" Grid.Row="0"/>-->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What is `ContentPanel`? is it a Canvas? Could you add the XAML code for `ContentPanel` and `OrginalImage`?

Comment: hi Truong, had you tried my answer? does it work for you?

Comment: hi kennyzx. I had tried your answer and same result with my function (code behind in my post). But if i change root control from Grid to Canvas. Its get position closer. Thank

Answer (score 0):

To get the position

```
void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e) 
        { 
            TouchPoint touchPoint = e.GetTouchPoints(this.ContentPanel).FirstOrDefault(); 
            if (touchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Up) 
            MessageBox.Show("Selected coordinates:"+touchPoint.Position.X + "," + touchPoint.Position.Y);//Displaying x&y co-ordinates of Touch point 
        }
```

Source taken from : [This Link](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/08/windowsphone-get-x-and-y-coordinates-of.html)...

Comment: hi Vijay, i saw the link you recommend but i think it use for whole screen. In my case, i want to add control in image area only.

Comment: i tried you code. Same result with my code. I think problem is Textbox margin thickness not same with x, y coordinate

Comment: Put you image in Canvas and write event for Handle Tap and try to get the position.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `TextBox` is located in the center of the `ContentPanel` (which is a Grid) by default. You expected it to be located to the Top Left corner, right? That is true if `ContentPanel` is a Canvas, but not for Grid.

You could verify this by setting the `TextBox's Margin` as (0,0,0,0), notice that the `TextBox` will be in the center, not at the Top Left corner.

```
double top= 0; double right = 0; double bottom =0; double left=0;
newtext.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Now the fix: setting HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties.

```
TextBox newtext = new TextBox(); 
newtext.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
newtext.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```